# Saving to Parse.com database in applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com as my backend and want to update something in the database (a badge count) when the app enters the background. I am using this code below. I understand that this only allows for five seconds of operation time though. Is there a way to extend this time?

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    curentInstallation.badge = self.messageCount;
    currentInstallation.badge = 0;
    [currentInstallation saveEventually];

}
```

I have also read: *If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.* By supporting background execution does it mean having the values enabled in the Plist and the user allows for background execution or does it refer to old versions of iOS that don't do backgrounding? Any pointers on this would be great. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

The example code shows you how to create a background task. In that you could use the normal Parse API with callback. Inside this callback, you have to call

```
[application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

To let iOS know, when you're done.

You should also make use of [backgroundTimeRemaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/backgroundTimeRemaining) and schedule a timer fire event before you don't have any time left and make sure you call `saveEventually`, so parse can (in this case) at least save the changes the next time the user opens your app!

Comment: Been taking a look at that for bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^, where do I declare MyTask? Is it a method? Just don't understand that part of the code.

Comment: "MyTask" is just a name you provide for debugging. From Docu: "The name to display in the debugger when viewing the background task. If you specify nil for this parameter, this method generates a name based on the name of the calling function or method."

Comment: got it thanks buddy. Do the application background modes  need to be enabled (in the Plist) for this to work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to. And be careful with the backgroundTimeLeft since the actual time you get when you deploy via App Store is much shorter (30sec to a minute) then what's shown to you when you adhoc deploy to your device

Comment: Yeah, it's a single API call. Should be long enough. Thanks